# Validating a nested form group

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I created a form group in Angular 2 using reactive forms. I am quite new to it so i apologise in advance if the question makes no sense. I created a nested group within the parent group which has its own custom validator. In the below code snippet, the nested group is customRolesGroup. The validator is working for the nested form group but the parent form has a control which also calls this same validation method. The issue i have is, whenever the parent control calls out to the validation method, i need it to automatically set the nested group errors to be either null or false.

Is there anyway i can pass in the nested group control to the validator (customRoleValidation) from the parent control or patch the nested form control errors to be null?

```js
public createNewForm(event: string) : FormGroup {
      this.addUserForm = this.fb.group({
          firstName: ['',
              [   Validators.required,
                  Validators.maxLength(AddUserConstants.maxLengthName)
              ]],
          lastName: ['',
              [   Validators.required,
                  Validators.maxLength(AddUserConstants.maxLengthName)]
              ],
          email: ['',
              [   Validators.required,
                  Validators.maxLength(AddUserConstants.maxLengthEmail),
                  Validators.pattern(AddUserConstants.emailPattern),
              ]],
          roleSelection: [AddUserConstants.roleCustom,
              [   Validators.required,
                  this.customRoleValidation
              ]],
          admin: '',
          customRolesGroup: this.fb.group({
              salesPerson: '',
              inventoryManager: '',
              creativeReviewer: '',
              reporter: '',
              observer: '',
          }, {validator: this.customRoleValidation}),
      });

      this.addEditButtonText = AddUserConstants.addUserCreateButton;
      this.addEditDBCall = AddUserConstants.addEvent;
      this.modalTitle = AddUserConstants.addUserTitle;


      return this.addUserForm;

  }
}


public customRoleValidation(c: AbstractControl) : {[key: string]: boolean} | null {

    let rolesSelectedCounter : number = 0;
    let noCustomRolesSelected : boolean;

    Object.keys(c.value).map(function(key) {
        if (c.value[key] == "" || c.value[key] == false) {
            rolesSelectedCounter++;
        }
        rolesSelectedCounter == Object.keys(c.value).length ? noCustomRolesSelected = true :                                    noCustomRolesSelected = false;
    });

    if (typeof c.parent !== 'undefined') {
        if (noCustomRolesSelected && c.root.value.roleSelection == AddUserConstants.roleCustom) {
            return { 'noCustomRoleSelected': true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the **this.customRoleValidation** from the parent control instead of nested form group. There you can get both parent control and nested form group control.

Comment: Glad to help you. @BrianM